# Linux Audit log rotation name and compression RHEL CentOS 7

Tags: centos, rhel, linux-audit

Want to set either a **weekly** or **monthly** saving of the real-time `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file to a compressed file having the name such as `audit_2020-05-05.log.gz`

In **RHEL/CentOS 7.x** is there an **elegant** way to make the following happen all within existing audit **.conf** files ?

Otherwise is the *best* way to simply do a root crontab that will run a homegrown bash shell script that will...

- `service auditd stop`
- `cp   /var/log/audit/audit.log   /var/log/audit/audit_<date>.log`
- `service auditd start`
- `gzip -9 /var/log/audit/audit_<date>.log`

I would prefer to make the above happen by doing it within the confines of the `/etc/audit/` files if that is possible which is why I am asking.  But I strongly want `audit_<date>.log.gz` files to come about every week/month with that specific file naming convention.

The ultimate goal is a reliable and robust way of managing the created audit log archives... keeping any one saved audit log text file to be less than 1GB in size uncompressed so adjusting the log saving/rotation accordingly.  But also to not lose any audit log or bring the system to single user mode based on audit.conf settings.  So any *better* way than what I am currently thinking I would be happy to hear about.

Answer (score 4):

By default, auditd in all versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux rotates its own log files automatically when they reach a certain size, as determined by the `max_log_file` setting in `auditd.conf` (which defaults to 6 megabytes)

1. **Replacing auto-rotation based on size with auto-rotation based on time**

Disable rotation in /etc/audit/auditd.conf so that:

```
max_log_file_action = ignore
```

2. **Tell auditd to reconfigure itself (applying your changes) by doing one of the following:**

> kill -HUP $(pidof auditd)   (Any version)

> systemctl reload auditd   (RHEL7)

> service auditd reload   (RHEL6 and earlier)

3. **To manually trigger auditd to rotate, it needs to receive a USR1 signal**

Simple solution for daily rotation: copy auditd.cron to cron.daily

```
~]# cp /usr/share/doc/audit-*/auditd.cron /etc/cron.daily
~]# chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/auditd.cron
~]# cat /etc/cron.daily/auditd.cron
#!/bin/sh

##########
# This script can be installed to get a daily log rotation
# based on a cron job.
##########

/sbin/service auditd rotate
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t auditd "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

**Implementing log compression**

auditd does not support log compression; however, it's trivial to update the above script to rename old audit.log.n files and compress them. A working example is provided for demonstration purposes.

*Follow the steps above to disable auto-rotation based on size*

*Replace the previously-created script with the following code:*

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

FORMAT="%F_%T"  # Customize timestamp format as desired, per `man date`
                # %F_%T will lead to files like: audit.log.2015-02-26_15:43:46
COMPRESS=gzip   # Change to bzip2 or xz as desired
KEEP=5          # Number of compressed log files to keep
ROTATE_TIME=5   # Amount of time in seconds to wait for auditd to rotate its logs. Adjust this as necessary

rename_and_compress_old_logs() {
    for file in $(find /var/log/audit/ -name 'audit.log.[0-9]'); do
        timestamp=$(ls -l --time-style="+${FORMAT}" ${file} | awk '{print $6}')
        newfile=${file%.[0-9]}.${timestamp}
        # Optional: remove "-v" verbose flag from next 2 lines to hide output
        mv -v ${file} ${newfile}
        ${COMPRESS} -v ${newfile}
    done
}

delete_old_compressed_logs() {
    # Optional: remove "-v" verbose flag to hide output
    rm -v $(find /var/log/audit/ -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*audit\.log\..*(xz|gz|bz2)$' | sort -n | head -n -${KEEP})
}

rename_and_compress_old_logs
service auditd rotate
sleep $ROTATE_TIME
rename_and_compress_old_logs
delete_old_compressed_logs
```

Modify the declarations of `FORMAT`, `COMPRESS`, and `KEEP` as desired

Ensure the script is marked executable and set it to be called by cron at desired times (either via a normal cron job or by putting it in cron.daily as demonstrated above)

Comment: FYI: It looks like this answer is a reprint of https://access.redhat.com/solutions/661603

Comment: Why is this so DIY? What does this do that a regular logrotate configuration wouldn't do?